# handle nested object variables undefined errors in component inside - vuejs

Tags: vue.js

my vuejs app using long dot notation paths to access object elements eg:

```
<img :src="(row.item.product.images.size_m.path || '')" alt="img" />
```

if `product.images` is null, it throw error and stop whole component.. but in script functions, i can use

```
let val = row?.item?.product?.images?.size_m?.path || '';
```

without a problem, `?` cannot use in inside `template` i just need proper way to prevent this kind of undefined errors.

thank you

I'm currently doing creating method and pass data to it and get value, but it make complex when have to deal with lot of undefined values
eg:

```
  methods: {

    getImage(row){
      return row?.item?.product?.images?.size_m?.path || '';
    }
    },
```

Comment: Add getImage(row) in `computed`

Comment: the method you posted is exactly how you do it. if you do not like the complexity of this, you could use helper functions to easily flatten objects and refer to property on the first level.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan thanks you.. is `computed` area functions can take parameters?

Comment: @oshell thank you.. is that possible to use  `?` inside component template . ?

Comment: no you need to define a method, just like you did. if you do not want method for each deeply nested object you could use a general function like lodash get which works like this: `_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');`

Comment: You dont need parameters as long as the `row` is singular object data but if its an element of some array and your `<img src...` is inside a loop then yes you would need a method

Answer (score 0):

You can try get method of lodash library [Lodash Get method](https://lodash.com/docs/#get)

**get(row, 'item.product.images.size_m.path', '')**

It will auto resolved value if is *undefined* and the third param is default if it can not reach to final path.